# How to have custom name for ignite cache model column name

Tags: c#, ignite

I'm trying to achieve having a custom name for C# Cache model column name created in ignite. currently the behavior is like below.

```
public class MeetingManager
    {
        [QuerySqlField]
        public long MeetingId { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField]
        public string MeetingName { get; set; }
    }
var meetingCache = igniteClient.GetOrCreateCache<long, Meeting>(new CacheClientConfiguration
                    {
                        Name = typeof(Meeting).Name,
                        SqlSchema = "USERSCHEMA",
                        QueryEntities = new[] { new QueryEntity(typeof(long), typeof(Meeting)) }
                    });
```

with the above the to query the cache via sql.
i'm doing this `select * from USERSCHEMA.MEETING WHERE MEETINGID=1`

but i have to achieve something like below
`select * from USERSCHEMA.MEETING_MANAGER WHERE MEETING_ID=1`
basically i'm trying to have same for both RDBMS and ignite so that the same query can be executed here and there.

Answer (score 2):

Won't `QuerySqlFieldAttribute#Name` work here?

Alternatively, it's possible to create your schema manually:

```
      QueryEntities = new[]
        {
            new QueryEntity
            {
                KeyTypeName = "Integer",
                ValueTypeName = "java.lang.String",
                TableName = "Table1",
                Fields = new[]
                {
                    new QueryField("length", typeof(int)), 
                    new QueryField("name", typeof(string)) {IsKeyField = true, DefaultValue = "defName"},
                    new QueryField("location", typeof(string)) {NotNull = true},
                },
                Aliases = new [] {new QueryAlias("length", "len") },
                ....
```